# linux sort order that I don't understand

Tags: linux, sorting

I notice the following sort outputs. Who understands why the '.' gets sorted in front the first time and at the end the second time?

I was trying to debug a program which looks up lines in a large sorted file, but the culprit seems to be my expectation/understanding of linux sort.

```
$ sort --debug
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
/mnt/x/E
/mnt/x/.
<ctrl-D>
/mnt/x/.
________
/mnt/x/E
________
$ sort --debug
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
/mnt/x/Ed
/mnt/x/.T
<ctrl-D>
/mnt/x/Ed
_________
/mnt/x/.T
_________
$
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it is written by `sort` itself when you run it with `--debug`. At least, also to me in `sort GNU 8.21`.

Comment: that was added by the --debug option, that "highlightes" the parts used as sort key

Comment: note it does not have to do with the `--debug` option. A sample file with these lines and then `sort file` does have the same behaviour. At least to me.

Answer (score 3):

It's not that "." comes before or after other characters - it's that it's not being examined at all; it's sorting purely based on the alphabetic characters.

In your first example, `<end-of-string>` sorts before `E`; in the second example, `E` sorts before `T`.

This behaviour is dependent on the locale settings for collation. You can influence this with environment variables, such as `LC_COLLATE`:

```
$ env LC_COLLATE=C sort
/mnt/x/Ed
/mnt/x/.T
^D
/mnt/x/.T
/mnt/x/Ed
$ env LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort
/mnt/x/Ed
/mnt/x/.T
^D
/mnt/x/Ed
/mnt/x/.T
$
```

Under the `C` locale, all ASCII characters are considered, and are sorted in their ASCII order; in many other locales punctuation is ignored - this is presumably what is causing the behaviour you're seeing.

You can examine your locale settings using the `locale` command.